# Mutex behavior on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, mutex

I've the following code...

On one machine it throws ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED and on other it throws ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS (Handle is not NULL). I'd like to understand why two different behaviors. On both the machines user is a domain user part of local system administrators group. I tried running three instances simultaneously.

---

```
#include <windows.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void * _hMutex = NULL;

void createMyMutex()
{
    _hMutex = CreateMutex( 
            NULL,              // default security attributes
            false,             // initially not owned
            L"LockTest");      // named mutex

        if (_hMutex == NULL) 
        {
            cout<< GetLastError()<< " Error creating mutex handle"<<endl;
            Exit(0);
        }
        if(GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
        {
            cout<< GetLastError()<< " Mutex already created" <<endl;
        }   
}

void Lock()
{
    cout<<"Acquiring Lock..."<< endl;
    if(_hMutex != NULL)
        WaitForSingleObject(_hMutex, INFINITE);
    cout<< "Acquired Lock." <<endl;
}

void Unlock()
{
cout<< "Releasing Lock..." <<endl;
    if(_hMutex != NULL)
       ReleaseMutex(_hMutex);
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    cout<<"Creating lock"<<endl;
    createMyMutex();
    cout<<"Lock create success"<<endl;

    cout<<"Taking lock"<<endl;
    Lock();
    cout<<"Got the lock"<<endl;

    cout<<"Waiting for 20 seconds"<<endl;
    Sleep(20000);
    cout<<"Wait over"<<endl;


    cout<<"Releasing lock"<<endl;
    Unlock();
    cout<<"Lock released successfully"<<endl;

    cout<<"exiting the program"<<endl;
    return 0;
    }
```

---

Comment: `_hMutex` is a [reserved identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) in the global scope.

Comment: I actually have that in as a class member, for simplicity, I wrote the program without using class.

Comment: That's ok, then. Just make sure your members don't begin with a capital letter following the underscore, though, as that is reserved in any scope.

Comment: Were all three instances running in the same security context?  Are they running elevated?  What is different between the two machines, e.g., does one of them have UAC disabled?

Comment: there is not any difference and all run the same way. On one machine I get access denied and on the other I get already exists.

Answer (score 3):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> If the mutex is a named mutex and the object existed before this function call, the return value is a handle to the existing object, GetLastError returns `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`, *bInitialOwner* is ignored, and the calling thread is not granted ownership. However, if the caller has limited access rights, the function will fail with `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` and the caller should use the OpenMutex function.

So try using [`OpenMutex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684315%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead with just the `SYNCHRONIZE` access right.

Also note that the Windows type `BOOL` is different from the C++ type `bool`.  So you should use the corresponding values `TRUE` and `FALSE` when calling Windows API functions that take `BOOL`, **not** `true` and `false`.

Comment: The problem is, sometimes even for the first run it throws access denied error with just once instance of the program is running.

Comment: The behavior should be consistent when the user permissions are same. would like to unserstand why there are two different behaviors?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're getting the `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` when calling `createMyMutex();` and the `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` when calling `Lock();`. I's suggest to choose an object name in the global namespace. So you better use something like

```
CreateMutex( NULL, FALSE, "Global\\LockTest" );
```

See [Object Namespaces on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684295%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for details.

Comment: It is always at the mutex creation not at the lock.